# Function that returns an array used multiple times gives same value every time

Tags: c

I want to make a function that returns an int array. However I am having difficulties as this attempt will return the same value for both `out1` and `out2`

```c
int * foo(int bar) {
    static int fizz[2] = {0, 0};
    fizz[0] = bar;
    fizz[1] = bar + 1;
    return fizz;
}

int main() {
    int *out1 = foo(1);
    int *out2 = foo(2);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n(%d, %d)", out1[0], out1[1], out2[0], out2[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
(2, 3)
(2, 3)
```

And then this solution does not compile as I am returning the address of a local variable (which is what lead me to attempt the `static` keyword in the first place.

```c
int * foo(int bar) {
    int fizz[2] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    fizz[0] = bar;
    fizz[1] = bar + 1;
    return fizz;
}

int main() {
    int *out1 = foo(1);
    int *out2 = foo(2);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n(%d, %d)", out1[0], out1[1], out2[0], out2[1]);
}
```

So I know why this code is not working but I have no clue what other methods I could attempt to successfully write this function.

Comment: When you declare a variable as static, it does two things - it makes the variable permanent so it doesn't get destroyed when it goes out of scope, and it ensures that there's only one copy of the variable.  So when you re-enter the function, you're using the same variable again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt is close, and certainly along the right path. However, the return value from the `malloc` function is a pointer (*not* an array) and the `fizz` variable should be declared as such (a pointer-to-integer, or `int*`).

Your concern about this "returning the address of a local variable" is not relevant, in this case; what you are returning is the ***value*** of a local variable, which just happens to be an address. The value of that address, returned by `malloc`, will be *copied* to the value returned by the function.

Also, when using `malloc` , never forget to release the memory when you're finished with it, using the `free` function.

Here's a working code sample, which is changed very little from your second snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* foo(int bar)
{
    int *fizz = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); // Save the allocated pointer (locally)...
    fizz[0] = bar;
    fizz[1] = bar + 1;
    return fizz;              // ... and return a COPY of the value of that address!
}

int main()
{
    int* out1 = foo(1);
    int* out2 = foo(2);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n(%d, %d)", out1[0], out1[1], out2[0], out2[1]);
    // Don't forget to free the allocated memory...
    free(out1);
    free(out2);
}
```

---

It's not *entirely* clear whether or not you understand *why* your first snippet gives the same values for both `out1` and `out2`. So, just in case: the `static int fizz[2]` line declares a **fixed** block of memory – though it's only accessible, by name, from within that function. Each call to `foo` will return a pointer to that (same) memory, and the `printf` call will display the values assigned to its elements in the most recent (latest) update.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is also fine, only when to print the result....

```
int* foo(int bar) {
static int fizz[2]={0,0};
fizz[0] = bar;
fizz[1] = bar + 1;
return fizz;
}

int main() {

   int* out1=foo(1);
   printf("%d,%d\n", out1[0], out1[1]);
   int* out2=foo(2);
   printf("%d,%d \n", out2[0], out2[1]);

return 0 ;
}
```

gives the result :

```
1,2
2,3
```